# Cannot connect through RDP into remote HDinsight cluster

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

I have created an HDInsight cluster in azure platform. I have enabled the remote connection with a remote desktop user configured. I cannot connect through the file that is downloaded. It says, server is off or does not have permission for remote access ..etc. How can I connect to the HDinsight remo

Comment: Only Windows-based cluster supports RPD connection.  There are two users configured, one is the HTTP user, the other is RDP user. They must have different usernames.  Make sure you use the RDP user to login.

Comment: Is the cluster provisioned into a VNET?